# How to get t statistics and/or p value in R using the semPLS package?

Tags: r, least-squares, structural-equation-model

I'am currently trying to do Structural equation modelling in R with the PLS approach.

With the package semPLS I was able to create the model and get the path coefficients.
After that I used the boot package and the function "bootsempls" in order to bootstrap my estimations.
But with the function "summary" it only gives me a bca confidence interval, but I would like to have t statistics or p values for my path coefficients.

Does anybody know how I can get them? Or am I misssing the statistical knowledge in order to calculate them from the bca confidence interval?:/

Comment: I have voted to migrate this question to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), because it seems to be more a question about statistics than about R code.

Answer (score 0):

You get a (non-parametric) confidence interval. Why do you want a p-value? The confidence interval gives more information. It is not obvious to get a p-value from a non-parametric CI, because the original distribution is unknown (PLS is quite a distribution-free estimation) - this is why needs to do bootstrapping, to get some kind of estimate uncertainty without assuming any data distribution. I would suggest: just to take the CI (and forget the p-value).